# Show measures are aboslutely continuous based on relationship between integrals of certain functions

Tags: real-analysis

So I have the following question.

> Suppose $\mu$ is a regular Borel measure on $[0,1]$ and $\{f_n\}\subseteq L^1[0,1]$ s.t. $|f_n(x)|\leq |f(x)| \ [m]$ a.e. and $f\in L^1[0,1].$
>   Given $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1 \phi(x)f_n(x)dx=\int_0^1 \phi(x)d\mu(x)$$ for all $\phi\in\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ show that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t to the Lebesgue measure $m.$

So I have tried a few different routes, but each ran into different issues.

First I noted that I had $$\int_{[0,1]} \phi(x)d\mu(x)\leq\int_{[0,1]} |f(x)|\phi(x)dm(x).$$ I considered continuous functions $\phi_n(x)$ as illustrated below.

[image]

Now using these and the above inequality and LDCT, I was able to get for intervals
$$\mu([a,b]) \leq \int_{[a,b]} |f(x)|dm(x).$$
Since I had it for intervals I get it for open sets (since we can represent them as the disjoint union of open intervals). The issue came in when I tried to get it for compact sets, because
$$\mu(K)=\mu([0,1])-\mu(K^c) \not\leq \int_{[0,1]}|f(x)|dm(x) - \int_{K^c}|f(x)|dm(x)=\int_{K} |f(x)|dm(x).$$

After working with this angle for a while I threw up my hands and tried route 2. I decided maybe it would be beneficial to keep the limits and just use the LDCT to move them in and out (since $f_n$'s are bounded and any continuous function on [0,1] is necessarily bounded as well). However, LDCT requires the functions to converge pointwise. Fatou's Lemma and its corrallaries (those I know) also aren't quite strong enough to get the job done here.

My final attempt before admitting defeat (although hopefully temporarily) was to try and invoke Lusin's Theorem. I don't have $\mu$ is complete, but I figured if AC held for the completion of $\mu$ it would for $\mu$ as well. Letting $m(A)=0,$ I would have
$$\mu(A)=\int_{E^c} \phi(x)d\mu(x)+\mu(E\cap A) < \int_{E^c}\phi(c)d\mu(x)+\delta$$
Unless I can manipulate $E^c$ more however I don't see how I can get the result. Ideally I would like $\phi(x)\equiv0$ on $E^c\setminus A$ and so I'd have the result by the completeness of $m.$ I just am unsure of how to justify such a claim.

Any assistance, corrections or guidance is most appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What does AC mean here?

Comment: Sorry, I've been staring at it too long. It means absolutely continuous. I will edit it. I had trouble coming up with a good short title for this question.

Comment: so $f$ is Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is assumed to be Lebesgue integrable. I'll add that in.

Comment: I think it similar to that question. You only need the limit argument for $f_n$: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1369817/251257